# how can I set focus cursor to my jQuery combobox input

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox, focus, setfocus

I have input many combobox

[image]

this is use for input with barcode.

at begining, focus in first row, then when enter key pressed I want to set focus to second row (in case combobox jQuery input type)

this is my combobox code

```
                $('#ManifestDetail'+i+'AwbNumber').combobox({});
```

I already handle enter key to second row, but .focus() just working for input type text, or text area, I was tried to using .focus() in my combobox but not working

[image: I have set focus here]

somebody help me for this case?
thanks before.

Comment: You have to listen to keystorkes and when `Enter` arrives, use a `.focus()` method on the next combobox.

Comment: yes, sure, I have listened about keystrokes. and enter already arrived, but now I unsuccessful to make focus in combobox, if focus at input which is not combobox type, like text, textarea it's work

Comment: Find or call your Id´element (combobox in this case) and use focus into it... I will use an event´s element (onblur, onchange, or whatever you want) and I´ll set focus in the next element in a Jquery´s function.

Comment: i dont know if combo boxes have a focused css by standard. so try creating a :focus event for the comboboxes in your css file

Comment: @EliasMP : yes, I have tried that way, that step, I use keypress event element, but when I set focus to next element with .focus() jQuery, not working at all $("#nextIdElement").focus(), but while I set focus to input type (not combobox) it's working;

Alexander : Can I focus with jss in combobox ? have you try it?